# defining child page permalink

Tags: permalinks

I have written a page whose slug is `mypage`. I have set it as a child of `mymainpage`.
However, I want that its permalink is `www.example.org/mypage` in place of `www.example.org/mymainpage/mypage`. Is it possible?

Comment: You should have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262919/how-to-remove-parent-slug-from-child-pages-permalink

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin:
[**Custom Permalinks**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/)

In this plugin you can edit permalink structure of page and post.